# Is it possible to get the value of an item contained in Django's "changed_data" list?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in my Django application:

```
if 'book' in authorForm.changed_data:
   #Do something here...
```

I realize Django can tell me which values have changed in my form by utilizing the "changed_data" list object, but I'd like to know the new values of the fields that have changed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to my original question is "No".

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... Try this:

```
if authorForm.is_valid() and 'book' in authorForm.changed_data:
    new_value = authorForm.cleaned_data['book']
```

Comment: The short answer to my original question is "No".  However, your answer is appreciated and I'll give you credit. :)